# CRON Job Schedule issues

Tags: cron, scheduling

I want to schedule a job for 3rd Friday of every month, 1 AM .
I checked few cron entry websites for that didn't work for me.

I was also checking for some awk options for this so far not successful with that.
Can you guys help me with that?

I tried to run this for today the cron is working fine but the script is running continuously at the same point and not getting completed :

```
0 1 15-21 * * test $(date +\%u) -eq 5 && echo "3rd friday" && Extract_Param.sh /landing/file/ABC/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, when you give both a day-of-month and a day-of-week in a crontab entry, this means either one is sufficient. (Didn't know that either, but [the manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/crontab.5.html) says so.) This means we can't simply calculate that the 3rd friday is a friday that is between the 15th and 21st of the month.

Fortunately, the above-linked man page also advises us:

> One can, however, achieve the desired result by adding a test to the command (see the last example in EXAMPLE CRON FILE below).
>
> […]
>
> ```
> # Run on every second Saturday of the month
> 0 4 8-14 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 6 && echo "2nd Saturday"
> ```

so you should be fine with

```
0 1 15-21 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 5 && echo "3rd friday"
```

Comment: So this is how i put the entry as i am passing an argument to ithe script i have to schedule?
0 1 15-21 * *    test $(date +\%u) -eq 5 && echo "3rd friday" && Extract_Param.sh /landing/file/ABC/file.txt

Comment: Can you please tell me if there is any error in the cron entry?

Comment: @user3901666: well, you should leave off the `&& echo "3rd friday"`, other than that, that looks good.

Comment: But, I was able to get the cron run with your command , I just had to add a sh before the script.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Is this && echo "3rd friday" not required??

Comment: @user3901666: yes, it's just an example of "something that will happen".

Comment: @user3901666: Yes, the first (day-of-week) of the month will always be in days 1-7, because day 8 is the same as day 1. 8-14 are the second occurences, 15-21 the third, 22-28 the fourth.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: How would i do the same for last saturday of every month? I certainly can't keep 22-28 there?